# rsync: rename ... -> ...: No such file or directory (2) Azure Linux App Service

Tags: azure-web-app-service, apache2, azure-linux

After adding a custom startup command as per the docs I began receiving error `rsync: rename ... -> ...: No such file or directory (2)`. The first deployment worked but consecutive deployments failed. Upon further inspection I observed that the startup script was locked and indicated `permission denied` when opening. This was because I included `apache2ctl -D FOREGROUND` which is blocking and held the startup script open.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that somewhere along the way oryx was updated to automatically append apache start and the azure docs don't seem to indicate this fact. So simply do NOT include `apache2ctl -D FOREGROUND` in your startup script and you should be fine. Note I'm using PHP 7.4 in linux and I specified the startup command through the portal Configuration - General Settings (not via cli).